# SPSS logistic regression

Tags: statistics, spss

I'm wondering if there is a way to get many single covariate logistic regression. I want to do it for all my variables because of the missing values. I wanted to have a multiple logistic regression but I have too many missing values. I don't want to compute a logistic regression for each variable in my DB, is there any automatic way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can code it using SPSS syntax.

For example:

```
LOGISTIC REGRESSION VARIABLES F2B16C -- Dependent variable


  /METHOD=BSTEP -- Backwards step - all variables in then see what could be backed out

  XRACE BYSES2 BYTXMSTD F1RGPP2 F1STEXP XHiMath  -- Independent variables

  /contrast (xrace)=indicator(6)  -- creates the dummy variables with #6 as the base case

  /contrast (F1Rgpp2)=indicator(6)

  /contrast (f1stexp)=indicator(6)

  /contrast (XHiMath)=indicator(5)

  /PRINT=GOODFIT CORR ITER(1) 

  /CRITERIA=PIN(0.05) POUT(0.10) ITERATE(20) CUT(0.5).`
```

If you do that you can also tell it to keep records with missing values where appropriate.
add /MISSING=INCLUDE

If anyone knows of a good explanation of the implications of including the missing values, I'd love to hear it.